# java function random number between -0.5 and 0.5 with gausian distobution

Tags: neural-network, gaussian, perceptron

I'm currently trying to make a random number between -0.5 and 0.5 in this way:

```
public static double RandomNumberGenerator(long seed)
{
    Random r = new Random(seed);
    return r.nextDouble() >= 0.5? 0.5 : -0.5;

    //PRINTING AND USAGE, SHOULD GO ABOVE
    //System.out.println("Object after seed 12222222: " + RandomNumberGenerator(12222222) );
}
```

Which I then execute like this:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < weights_one.length ; j++) 
    {
        weights_one[j] = RandomNumberGenerator( System.currentTimeMillis() );
    }
```

But it's really dysfunctional, because I always end up with weights that will be the same, i.e.

```
weights_one[0]: -0.5
weights_one[1]: -0.5
weights_one[2]: -0.5
weights_one[3]: -0.5
weights_one[4]: -0.5
```

which is not good, they should be gausianly distributed, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Random class create pseudo random numbers. I found two mistakes in your code:

1. For every cycle iteration you create one random instance. Just create one at the beginning of the for.
2. Random generate numbers between [0 ,1]. To translate to the interval [-0.5, 0.5] just subtract 0.5 to random function.

Your code can be replaced with:

```
Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
for (int j = 0; j < weights_one.length ; j++) 
{
    weights_one[j] = r.nextDouble() -0.5;
}
```

Comment: I've been working on this, this project- not exactly this function, for so many hours my brain is on fire- can you show me what you mean?

Comment: i just modified the answer to show you what i mean.